# Error Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: NDVI

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying export NDVI result to CSV file for 35 shapefiles farmers in Earth Engine. But it did not work. I tried find any solution from internet. How can I solve this problem?

```
var Akdarya = ee.FeatureCollection("users/xodjayevshovkat/Akdarya_GEE_35");

//Define a geometry.
Map.addLayer(Akdarya);

// Make the geometry a feature collection.

// Import S2 image collection.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  // Filter collection.
  .filterDate('2018-05-01','2018-09-30')
  .filterBounds(Akdarya)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20);

// Define a cloud masking function.
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
  var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1))
};


//

// Define an index function (return only NDVI).
var NDVI = function(image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)', 
    {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'), 
      'RED': image.select('B4'), 
    }).rename('NDVI').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
};

// Apply the cloud mask function.
var NDVIcol = S2.map(maskcloud1)
 // Apply the NDVI transformation.
 .map(NDVI);

// Calculate the per-pixel median/mean NDVI for all images in collection.
var NDVImed = NDVIcol.mean();

// Define vis params.
var NDVIvis = {min: -0.001, max: 0.9, palette: 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,' +
    '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301'};

//




// create a collection of the NDVI

var NDVIclip = NDVImed.clipToCollection(Akdarya)



// get the mean value for the region from each image
var ts = S2.map(function(image){
  var date = image.get("DATE_ACQUIRED")//.format("Y-M-D");
  var mean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: Akdarya,
    scale: 30
  });

// and return a feature with 'null' geometry with properties (dictionary)  
  return ee.Feature(null, {'mean': mean.get('NDVI'),
                            'date': date})
});

// Export a .csv table of date, mean NDVI for watershed
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ts,
  description: 'NDVI',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping over the `S2` collection and try to extract the mean `NDVI`. That collection doesn't contain `NDVI`. You probably wanted to map over `NDVIcol`.

When you're getting errors in exports, try to print the collection you're exporting. It will give you a lot faster feedback on what errors you might have.

```
var ts = NDVIcol.map(function(image){
  var date = image.get("DATE_ACQUIRED")//.format("Y-M-D");
  var mean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: Akdarya,
    scale: 30
  });

// and return a feature with 'null' geometry with properties (dictionary)  
  return ee.Feature(null, {'mean': mean.get('NDVI'),
                            'date': date})
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c0ef682554ed8c442840ea8a5169cebf

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please advice how can I calculate and make NDVI result for each shapefile in one horizontal line in excel. I would be grateful for your efforts

Comment: Submit that as a separate question.